# Some of our Android in-app products are subscriptions, some are not, is this allowed?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Our Android app is attempting to get the prices of our in-app products from Google Play. Some of our in-app products are subscriptions, some aren't. When calling the in-app billing service's `getSkuDetails` method to get prices, we're only allowed to pass in a single `type` string as the 3rd parameter.

Right now that string is set to "inapp", but it won't work unless all our in-app products are of that type. So it makes me wonder: can you have different in-app product types in Android? For example, can some products be subscriptions, and can others be consumable?

Our code is below, thanks for any help anyone can give.

```
IInAppBillingService service = activity.getBillingService();

ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
skuList.add("in_app_subscr_1");
skuList.add("in_app_subscr_2");
skuList.add("in_app_non_subscr_1");

Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
Bundle skuDetails = service.getSkuDetails(3, 
    activity.getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it should be allowed. Try maintaining two different `skuList` and pass it to `getSkuDetails` with respective product type: `inapp` for an in-app product and `subs` for subscriptions.

You might have to follow separate workflow for in app product and subscription. E.g. to retrieve information about purchases made by a user from your app, call the `getPurchases` method  with the product type parameter set to "`inapp`" for in-app product.

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
```

And to query for active subscriptions, use the `getPurchases` method with the product type parameter set to "`subs`".

```
Bundle activeSubs = mService.getPurchases(3, "com.example.myapp",
                   "subs", continueToken);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, that makes a lot of sense!